# Average Number of Roots of a Polynomial modulo p

Tags: modular-arithmetic, roots, irreducible-polynomials, average

Let $f \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ be an irreducible non-constant polynomial, and consider this polynomial modulo $p$ for each prime $p$. On average, how many roots does $f$ have modulo $p$? I.e., if $r(p)$ denotes the number of roots of $f$ modulo $p$, what is
\begin{equation}
\lim_{X \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\pi(X)}\sum_{p \leq X}r(p) \ ?
\end{equation}
where $\pi(X)$ is the prime counting function. If the degree of $f$ is $1$, then the answer is trivially $1$. If the degree of $f$ is $2$, then by Quadratic Reciprocity and Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions, you can again show the answer is $1$.

Does this quantity always exist? Is it equal to 1? Even information on other specific cases, such as cubic or quartic irreducible polynomials, would be helpful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This quantity always exists and is always equal to $1$. By [Chebotarev's density theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebotarev527s_density_theorem), the density of primes $p$ such that $f$ has $k$ roots $\bmod p$ is equal to the proportion of elements in the Galois group of $f$ which fix $k$ roots when acting on the roots. Since the Galois group acts transitively on the roots, the average number of fixed points is $1$ by Burnside's lemma.